# Python - Number Racing 2 Random generated Players

Tags: python, dictionary, pygame

Im trying to get a ouput that each round you choose a number between 1 and 3 and so do your two opponents. If a player's number 
is unique then they move forward that many steps. If another player also chooses the same number, 
neither of those players move. The first player to get to 10 or greater wins, but it is possible that 2 or 3 
players could cross the line at the same time, in which case there will be multiple winners who share 
the glory.

---

What i have so far.

```
def test():
print("Me\t\tPositions: 0\nGabriel\t\tPositions: 0\nJoy\t\tPositions: 0")
scoreLimit = 10       
wins = {"Me":'0', "Gabriel":'0', "Joy":'0'}

randomGuessP1 = randrange(1, 4) 
randomGuessP2 = randrange(1, 4)  

meGuess = input("Choices: ")
if meGuess != randomGuessP1 or randomGuessP2:
    meGuess += wins[key] --doesn't work.
for key in wins:
    print(key, wins[key])    
scoreLimit = 10
```

Been trying for awhile now, and i can't seem to get it right..
ive been alernating differnet styles and different ways on how to approach it... but this is the most stable ive come up with so far...

Example ouput = Choice = input from the player(Me)

```
Me Position: 0
Gabriel Position: 0
Joy Position: 0
Choice: 2
Me : 2 -> 2
Gabriel : 3 -> 0
Joy : 3 -> 0
Choice: 3
Me : 3 -> 2
Gabriel : 1 -> 1
Joy : 3 -> 0
Choice: 3
Me : 3 -> 5
Gabriel : 1 -> 1
Joy : 1 -> 0
Choice: 2
Me : 2 -> 7
Gabriel : 1 -> 1
Joy : 1 -> 0
Choice: 1
Me : 1 -> 8
Gabriel : 2 -> 3Joy : 3 -> 3
Choice: 2
Me : 2 -> 8
Gabriel : 2 -> 3
Joy : 3 -> 6
Choice: 3
Me : 3 -> 11
Gabriel : 2 -> 5
Joy : 1 -> 7
The winner is: Me
```

Don't really want any spoon feeding, but it would be nice, if not, a point to the right direction would be Lovely :)

Comment: describe the issue better, what is wrong here, make it clear in one sentence

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Me` key instead of just "key" for your dictionary:

```
meGuess = input("Choices: ")
if meGuess != randomGuessP1 or randomGuessP2:
    meGuess += wins['Me'] # use 'Me' rather than key
```

As for your game, you can use an outer loop to have multiple rounds:

```
while max(wins.values()) < scoreLimit: # loop until someone has scoreLimit wins
    # your game logic goes here:
```